# function has to be in 2 classes?

Tags: android, android-layout

When calling a function using the xml onclick, I have to place the function in my main class and the class linked to the XML.  I am not sure why it is making me do this.  If I remove the function from the main class it shows as incorrect in XML, and if I remove it from the linked class it shows as the function missing.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some relevant snippets of code and error messages so we can better understanding what you are doing/want to do

Comment: If I am not mistaken is it because I am using a method that sets to the new activity in my main class?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you didn't provide the requested information to help you

Comment: setContentView to new activity is why this was happening.  I wasn't loading the proper context for the functions.